# northwinddataset

Tags: c#, dataset, northwind

What does `northwinddataset = (NORTHWNDDataSet)bsEmployees.DataSource;`
actually mean in the code below? Its a datasource of northwinddataset instance?

```
 public partial class FormEdit : Form
 {
     BindingSource bsEmployees;
     NORTHWNDDataSet northwinddataset;                    
     EmployeesTableAdapter taEmployees;

     public FormEdit(BindingSource bsEmployees)            
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         this.bsEmployees = bsEmployees;
         taEmployees = new EmployeesTableAdapter();
         /***** This line *****/
         northwinddataset = (NORTHWNDDataSet)bsEmployees.DataSource;
         /*********************/

        }

        private void FormEdit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)               
        {
            try
            {
                tbLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsEmployees, northwinddataset.Employees.LastNameColumn.ColumnName);
                tbFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsEmployees, northwinddataset.Employees.FirstNameColumn.ColumnName);
                tbTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsEmployees, 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Greska: {0}", ex.Message));
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnSnimi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                   
        {
            bsEmployees.EndEdit();   
            if (taEmployees.Update(northwinddataset.Employees)> 0)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Recorded");
                 Close();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
northwinddataset = (NORTHWNDDataSet)bsEmployees.DataSource;
```

It's basically casting the `bsEmployees.DataSource` to a `NORTHWNDDataSet` type. This way you can use/call all functions/members available in `NORTHWNDDataSet`. Functions and members that probably aren't available on `bsEmployees.DataSource`.

This kind of operation is called [Casting (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Dear Jeff, I copied and pasted the title from the MSDN page. Corrected it. It's indeed just a cast.

Comment: I was actually referring to the "It's basically converting..." part. Nothing is being converted here (as far as I can tell from the code), just a cast.

Comment: thanks guys, so , is it used for text field data-bindings, can it be done more simpler...thanks again

Comment: @user1647555: I think no. If the cast is there it's because somewhere in the code bellow that point, members or functions/methods of `NORTHWNDDataSet` need to be called.